# How to provide certs to Java SOAP Client?

Tags: java, ssl, soap, https

I am trying to make a SOAP call using Axis over ssl (server is https://foo.com); where do I need to store the certificates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not providing a keystore explicit to the client then the client is using the default keystore in the JVM.

${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/security/cacerts